# MVC3, jQuery, Form submit: multiple submissions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following jQuery code to intercept a form submission and turn it into an Ajax call:

```
$("form.section_change").off("submit").on("submit", function () {
    var section = $(this).attr("data-section");
    var initializer = $(this).attr("data-initfunc");
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        error: function (a, b) {
            debugger;
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("div#" + section).html(result);
            bindExtenders();
            if (initializer != null) {
                var func = window[initializer];
                func();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Conceptually, what happens is the ajax call returns with html which is used to replace a div that's within the form tag. The bindExtenders() function call "rebinds" the jQuery bindings, including the one that is described by this snippet. The initializer function is an optional item that runs a specified javascript function.

When I submit the form the first time I'm on the page the callback is called just once, as expected. However, on subsequent submissions the callback is called multiple times (usually twice, but sometimes more than that).

I'd like to figure out how to do this so the callback only gets called once.

Comment: ->Declare a boolean variable in the actual javascript function. -> Initialize it to false. When the ajax call returns successfully update it to true. -> make an ajax call only when the boolean variable is false.

Comment: @ShaggyInjun that would probably work, but does not fix the problem.

Comment: As long as the variable is properly scoped and reset, I am not sure if there will be a problem. I am actually doing something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form.section_change', function() {
// ...
});
```

This way you don't need to rebind. See here: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks, Mallen. I didn't understand the concept of delegated selectors, but now that I've re-read the documentation I can see how they solve this problem quite neatly.